# BATCH CMD - Read INI file with specialcharacter

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, cmd, dos

I'm reading a config.ini file and i want to use KEY as a Variable name with VALUE as VALUE.

Config.ini

```
fbdestination=I:\WZPDA\workingfolder\stored
emailreport=xxx@xxxx.xxx
gmailudpw=USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

Im using:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^=" %%A IN (config.ini) DO (SET %%A=%%B)
```

Everything works well, but I have a problem with a complex password like:

```
myusername:!myp4ssw0rd!
```

Where if I try to ECHO $gmailudpw$ I only have :

```
myusername:
```

Is there a way to read !myp4ssw0rd! as a string and not as a variable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type "config.ini"') DO SET %%A
echo %fbdestination%
echo %emailreport%
echo %gmailudpw%
```

Comment: You don't get any visible result from command `type`. Just from the command `echo`. If you don't need it remove it. They just here as example.

Comment: I already removed echo command because I only need variables , but I had to put cls just after the "set %%A" to hide the whole ini content.